# Targeting single set of repeating elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create individual toggle for elements to show / hide.
All similar elements are responding to the action. How do I make this work for one particular set only? All the similar sections are getting toggled currently

Heres a fiddle of what I have created

https://jsfiddle.net/bqu0hznf/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary panel-custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
                </div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="acc-toggle">Basic panel example</a></h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor blah blah blah....</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary panel-custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
                </div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="acc-toggle">Basic panel example</a></h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor blah blah blah....</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary panel-custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
                </div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="acc-toggle">Basic panel example</a></h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor blah blah blah....</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $('.acc-toggle').click(function() {
        $( '.panel-custom  p , .panel-custom  .img-wrap img' ).fadeToggle('fast', 'linear');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this).closest('.panel-custom')` to find ancestor `.panel-custom` and then find `p, .img-wrap img` inside it like following.

```
$('.acc-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.panel-custom').find('p, .img-wrap img').fadeToggle('fast', 'linear');
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bqu0hznf/2/)**